# No internetconnection deploying Flutter App (release) on IOS(14+) device

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio

I'm trying to deploy my Flutter app on a iPhone IOS 14.4. IOS 14 don't support debug mode, so I run "flutter run --release". But when I open the application on my iPhone, it won't connect to the internet and my database. **It works well on my Xcode IOS simulator in debug mode**. I think it has something to do with release instead of debug.

[image: Application in release mode on IOS14 physical device]

Comment: What do you mean ios 14 doesn't support debug mode? did you get an error when you tried running debug mode?

Comment: iOS 14 won't allow iphone or ipad to run debug version of the app. We have to connect iphone / ipad to mac, run xcode. Click on run on xcode and the debug version of the app will start running in the device

Comment: @JideGuru yes, this error https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3I8yrpXoPok&ab_channel=LarryMoore

Comment: @BramvandeMunt I see it now. That happens after you've run the app and closed it.